# iCloud Services (iMessages/FaceTime/Continuity) Very Broken on my Mac

Tags: macos, icloud, messages, facetime, continuity

I'm having the most frustrating problem with iCloud on one of my Macs. Firstly, the Mac (a late 2012 iMac) was working flawlessly with all iCloud services up until a few days ago. Now, I am able to login to iCloud in my OS X user account fine, but no messages are ever displayed, no continuity features work, Messages will not send (some users show as not being registered with iMessages, some the message simply fails to send, and if I text myself I see the iMessage on that Mac only), FaceTime tries to dial but never completes, etc. This happens on all user accounts with all iCloud accounts on this Mac, not just mine. The same iCloud account works fine on a different computer (MacBook Air) and an iPhone running newest version of iOS 8.

I'm not at all sure if it's related, but I created a Mavericks VM in VMWare Fusion and signed in to iMessages on that VM on the iMac just before the time it started having issues, which worked and continues to work fine (the VM running on the "broken" iMac).

Here are some things that I've tried:

- reset the PRAM (many times!)
- reinstalled the OS (did not clear the drive first - didn't want to lose my stuff, that's next step. and also it seems insane)
- updated to 10.10.2 beta (this somehow got Messages to start sending SMS (although it is not enabled to do so on my iPhone!) messages but it is otherwise still broken)
- changed iCloud password to force all devices signed into account to sign out
- ensured that serial number shows in About This Mac
- changed my DNS records to google's, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
- tried other iCloud accounts
- turned the computer off for a few hours
- deleted ~/Library/Preferences/ directory and ~/Library/Messages/ directory to force full data reset of Messages app and iCloud preferences, then rebooted, but seems silly since all other users are having issues
- left iCloud logged out for a few hours and logged back in

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated it. I'm torn between calling Apple support (since the computer is out of AppleCare) and reformatting the computer to try to fix it.

edit: Mac has been connected to the network via WiFi and ethernet since problems began, no difference on either networks. Other Macs and iOS devices working fine on the network, and the network works great for all non-iCloud related stuff. I can go online, send files over network, etc. No issues.

Comment: Clarified, added paragraph at end about network, and I'm pretty sure I know what's in ~/Library/Preferences/ and ~/Library/Messages/ and feel comfortable deleting them, thanks

Comment: Why did you change your DNS servers to use the Google ones? Are these Google DNS servers particularly near from you?

Comment: I read about Yosemite having problems with resolving DNS due to its new mDNSresolver so I swapped my ISP DNS with the Google ones to see if it helped. I listed it here so it wouldn't be suggested again :)

Comment: I never saw such a problem except on cases were the location is configured to `Automatic` and the Mac spent its time switching between `Ethernet` and `Wi-Fi`. Changing the DNS server to a further one is a solution if your DNS server is a real failure. This **cannot** fix a supposed failing DNS client.

Comment: Yeah, I don't actually think I have a DNS issue. Based on your mention of the Automatic location, I created a new location, then rebooted, didn't seem to help.

Comment: You don't have to reboot when creating or switching locations. Just select it from the  menu. Is this new location on `Ethernet` or `Wi-Fi`?

Comment: WiFi, unfortunately I'm messing with it now over Remote Desktop so I can't physically plug in an ethernet cable, but I have the gut feeling it will have the same issue, can confirm shortly

Comment: @CamHenlin, create another account(OS X account, not iCloud account) and try the iCloud service

Comment: Yeah I stated that other user accounts don't work either sorry

Comment: Just tried plugged in with a physical ethernet cable on the new location, @danielAzuelos, still no dice

Comment: Make sure the date, time, and time zone are set correctly and check /etc/hosts file

Comment: Did you sign out of iCloud on both the real & VM OSes? Even de-authorise the VM too. A guess is that 'the cloud' thinks they are one & the same machine as the MAC addresses will match & has chosen the 'wrong' one to get friendly with.

Comment: Hi @nelson wondering if you could point out what I might look for in the hosts file? Honestly I do have a modification - my own public IP address mapped to "home" (forwarded at my Airport Extreme to my iMac on certain ports) (an identical mapping present on my MacBook Air which still works). I also run a nonstandard sshd_config so an old OS 9.2.2 PowerBook can ssh in with MacSSH. Neither of these things were problems in the past and both were overwritten by my OS reinstall (which didn't help, so I restored my changed versions).

Comment: Also yes @Tetsujin I kind of had the same gut feeling which was why I mentioned it myself and did spend some time messing around with that. Annoyingly, the same VM has no issues on other computers (a few Ubuntu 14.04-powered NUCs running VM Workstation 11) and playing around with iCloud configuration within the VM has no effect on the host apparently.

Comment: → CamHenlin: Please follow the problems separation method suggested by Tetsujin. Once done, shut down your VM, make a uniq connection (either `Ethernet` or `Wi-Fi`, but not both or random), test and report.

Comment: Hi,@CamHenlin, I propose to revert the hosts file to the default settings temporary, if the issue is resolved and that we can at least be able to think this issue related with hosts file

Comment: I have some good but frustrating news. iMessages, Continuity, and FaceTime now working again on this computer on its own, not sure why, but beginning to suspect this was something on Apple's end and some sort of blacklist on this computer, possibly caused by running a VM? The last thing that I tried was changing the location and switching to a wired ethernet connection, which I left it on the rest of the evening, although I did did a few hours of (unrelated) work on the computer without iCloud services working.

Answer (score 1):

I was following along because I had the same iMessage problem and just today I finally got it to work. I logged out of messages and iCloud and all my Macs, both virtual and physical machines. I think it was a VM I last logged out of that got things going going again.

Comment: Did your account work in the VM for a while before having issues? I've been playing with this some more and it seems like if I create a new VM (with new VMWare-generated serial number), I am able to stay logged in on that VM for a few days prior to having login issues.